# Returning a single column value from SQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I need to get the latest entry from my database, but not the autoincrement. 
This function is in my databasehandler:

```
public int getLatestRouteNumber()
{
    int number = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT MAX("+ KEY_ROUTENUMBER + ") FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst() && c != null) {
        number = c.getInt(3);
    }
    return number;
}
```

it craches at the line where "number = c.getInt(3).
The third column in my database exists and has data in it.

The error I'm gettin is "Couldn't read row 0, col 3 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it." I only need one value in the entire database, not even an entire row.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one column in cursor but trying to get value of 3rd column... Tat is the error

Change it to getInt(0);

Answer (score 0):

The returned result-set has nothing to do with table columns in your case. You should use

```
number = c.getInt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your resultset contains just one column and one row, basically a scalar value, it doesn't matter how many columns you have in your table, what you should consider here is the value you obtain from your query In your case just one value. Use

```
getInt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this :

```
String query = "SELECT MAX("+ KEY_ROUTENUMBER + ") as my_max FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS;
```

And :

```
columnIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("my_max");
number = c.getInt(columnIndex );
```

That's better than using indexes, indexes may be wrong if the raw query changes.

Answer (score 0):

getInt (3) returns the value of the 3rd column returned by the query. Your query only had 1 column.

Change getInt (3) to getInt (0)

Answer (score 0):

"c.getInt(3);" does not get the value from the column in your table, it gets it from the column in your cursor.

And you only selected one column into your cursor.

So I believe it should be "c.getInt(1);"

Comment: I think index here should be 0.

Comment: according to experience and the documentation, the columns indexing is 1-based. So the index should be 1. See the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)